# Update display_name of contact Android

Tags: android

This method always return false. I would like update display name of contact...

```
    public int updateDisplayName(long id, String newname) {
    Uri contact = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();     
    values.put(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, newname);     
    return context.getContentResolver().update(contact, values, null, null);
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks, 
Mateus

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising, this table is for aggregating information of multiple accounts and most of its data is only manipulated by the Contacts content provider itself.

See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

You would have to change the raw contact.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't understand how do... Can you post an sample of code?